# removing horizontal scrollbar for textarea

Tags: java, swing

I'm using Java Swing. I have a textarea in a panel. I don't need a horizontal scrollbar for that textArea, only a vertical scrollbar is needed. I disabled auto scrollbar options, but still the horizontal scrollbar is working. Please help me in thz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ta.setLineWrap(true)
```

> Sets the line-wrapping policy of the
>   text area. If set to true the lines
>   will be wrapped if they are too long
>   to fit within the allocated width. If
>   set to false, the lines will always be
>   unwrapped

Answer (score 1):

Scroll bar comes into text area when you are making your text area too small. This is because your the default **column** number in netbeans text area is **20**.

If you don't want the scroll bar being displayed ,  then take the textarea properties and change the column number to a value according to your size (say 10).

And the scrollbar will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples, the line wrap method and the scroll pane method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // example text
        String rep = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
        String all = rep;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
            all += "\n" + rep;

        // create the line wrap example
        JTextArea first = new JTextArea(all);
        first.setLineWrap(true);

        // create the scroll pane example
        JScrollPane second = 
            new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(all), 
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // lay it out
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        f.add(first);
        f.add(second);
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JTextPane don't have a method to enable or disable line wrap, one best choice is:

```
private JTextPane noWrapTextPane = new JTextPane() {
        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return getUI().getPreferredSize(this).width
                    <= getParent().getSize().width;
        }
    };
```

Comment: this question is about `JTextArea`, but better could be to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with one `JFrame` and two `JTextPane`s with diff settings, demonstrated your code snipped....

Comment: JTextArea have a method to enable or disable line wrap setLineWrap and method to enable or disable word wrap setWrapStyleWord...